# Running Oracle DataPatch after OPatch

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, windows-server

After patching an Oracle 12c database (Windows environment, container DB and 3 PDBs), is there any way to predict or estimate how long it will take to run DataPatch utility? Or to see how far along it has gotten once I start it? I'd like to be able to schedule a downtime window for an environment, but I can't seem to find anything that indicates how long that utility will be processing or what step out of how many steps it has completed.

I have a test environment of roughly similar size, but DataPatch doesn't provide a "percent complete" indicator or anything to let me know how far along it is. Datapatch has been running for roughly 1.5 hours in this test environment. I don't know if it's nearly finished or stalled out/locked up, or what it is doing. The SqlPatch folder contains 11 text log files, but none has a timestamp that has changed in the last hour.

Comment: The longest datapatch session I ever had, took about 2 minutes. 1.5 hours, that is abnormal. Just check what the database sessions are doing, there are some bugs related to this, for example `Bug 23124895 - Datapatch invocation against a PDB stuck (Doc ID 23124895.8)` or `Bug 22923409 - Mutiple datapatch sessions create locks in CDB (Doc ID 22923409.8)`.